# php email current page

Tags: php, email

I have made an ordering system that right now goes from the product form to a review page. I have the page set up to use PHP loops to show what products they selected form the prior page and it works great. Now I need to have a "order" button that emails the order on. I the practice of writing less code, I would like to not have to re write all the code to email this form on another php form. Is there a way to have email headers on this page and dump the generated html into the body of the email to send?

Here is how I loop the form contents from the previous page. Basically it goes though all the products and if its there, show them on the review. If not, dont.

```
for ($i=0; $i<8; $i++) {

        if (!empty($_REQUEST['driver'][$i]['select'])) {

            //add the club to the total of clubs
            $club = $_REQUEST['driver'][$i]['select'];
            array_push($club_total, $club);

            //add the price to the cost
            list($shaft, $price) = explode(":", $_REQUEST['driver'][$i]['shaft']);
            array_push($cost, $price);

            //show the user
            echo '<h3>' .$_POST['driver'][$i]['name']. ' - $'. money_format('%i', $price).'</h3>';
            echo '<ul>';
                if (!empty($_REQUEST['driver'][$i]['left'])) {
                    echo '<li><strong>Left Handed</strong></li>';
                }
                echo '<li>Length: '.$_POST['driver'][$i]['length']. '"</li>';
                echo '<li>Shaft: '.$shaft. '</li>';
                if (!empty($_REQUEST['driver'][$i]['hossel'])) {
                    echo '<li>Purist Hossel: ' .$_POST['driver'][$i]['hossel'].'</li>';
                }
                if (!empty($_REQUEST['driver'][$i]['color'])) {
                    echo '<li>Purist Color: ' .$_POST['driver'][$i]['color'].'</li>';
                }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
```

Comment: Instead of echoing you could store all the html in a variable and then echo it for the page as well as have it to use as the email body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could capture your html in the output buffer, then store it in a variable for later use (as in, putting it into the body of an email).

```
ob_start();
for ($i=0; $i<8; $i++) {
  // ... your code
}
$my_html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

then put `$my_html` as your email body and send it along.

The idea of putting it all in a variable the first time around also works, but this might save you some effort of rewriting everything.

Comment: How would I call mail function without a form then? When I wrap that all in the form the ob_get_contents only has the html not the php loops. If I just have the mail function in the body it works great but just sends the review right away (no action by user).

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but you would only execute the mail function after you've made sure the form has been submitted.

Comment: Sorry I got it. That was the perfect solution. I just stored the ob_get in a session and called an ajax function on a mail.php with the mail function and session in there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echoing out the html, build up a string, so $out .= "your html" etc, then you can easily set that lump of html to the body of the email function.

I am assuming you know how to code that, else I'll add code example for you.